# Kotlin equivalent for Swift's `@autoclosure`

Tags: kotlin

I'm wondering if there's an equivalent to [Swift's `@autoclosure` feature](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID543)

Essentially, I want to be able to create an argument in a function or constructor/initializer that can take another function that takes parameters, and execute it:

```
class Step(handler: () -> Unit) {

    init {
        handler()
    }

}

Step(aFunctionThatTakesParameters(parameter: String)) // <- Is there a way to get something like this working?
```

For reference, the equivalent code in Swift looks like this:

```swift
struct Step {

    init(_ handler: @autoclosure () -> Void) {
        handler()
    }

}

Step(aFunctionThatTakesParameters(parameter: ""))
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions I don't know what autoclosure is, but looks like you are describing a higher order function

Comment: Yeah that looks like it's on the right track, except an autoclosure essentially lets you pass in any expression and it will get executed at the point of calling `handler()`. I'd need a way to pass in _any_ function, rather than a function with a specific signature

Comment: maybe I am missing the point but that doesn't sound like a good idea. Why do you need that? How would the executed function know what parameters were passed to it or what they represent?

Comment: It's for a very specific use case in automation testing, but that's besides the point really! The Swift code above will call any expression (in this case `aFunctionThatTakesParameters(parameter: "")`) when `handler()` is called, so it doesn't matter what parameters are passed to it because it's not the step that cares about it, the step is just executing it when the step needs to.

Comment: then could you not pass an empty function that only functions as trigger, and invoke the actual function in the calling class when the 'trigger function' is invoked

Comment: Wouldn't I need to wrap that in `{}` though? That's essentially what `@autoclosure` is doing for us in the code above

Comment: yes but I mean you'd call it like `Step(handler = { realFunctionWithParams(param="") })` where 'handler' only functions as delegate

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid really, appreciate it's just sugar but the way we write our automation on iOS is really easy to read and write, although this doesn't add much extra to write it's not as clean. In any case, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I pulled open the Swift documentation for Auto closures at the link:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID543

That references this code:

```
var customersInLine = ["Chris", "Alex", "Ewa", "Barry", "Daniella"]
print(customersInLine.count)
// Prints "5"

let customerProvider = { customersInLine.remove(at: 0) }
print(customersInLine.count)
// Prints "5"

print("Now serving \(customerProvider())!")
// Prints "Now serving Chris!"
print(customersInLine.count)
// Prints "4"
```

I then wrote the following to translate from Swift to Kotlin:

```
val customersInLine = mutableListOf("Chris", "Alex", "Ema", "Barry", "Daniella")
println(customersInLine.size)
// Prints "5"

val customerProvider = { customersInLine.removeAt(0) }
println(customersInLine.size)
// Prints "5"

println("Now serving ${customerProvider()}!")
// Prints "Now serving Chris!"
println(customersInLine.size)
// Prints "4"
```

While this doesn't seem to give the expected output you are looking for, you could do something more along the lines of...

```
class Step (handler: () -> Unit) {
    init {
        handler()
    }
}

fun myParamFunction(a: String, b: String) {
    a + b
}

Step {
   myParamFunction("Hello ", "there") 
}
```

In this case, the best Kotlin can do is take a pure lambda function, and internally call a function that has been given parameters to be called.